Can Anyone Tell Me What I Am Missing Or What I Am Doing Wrong?
The problem is that data is not getting stored in database, getting an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Name')
this is my signup page code
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/signup", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
      });
  };
<form
          action="/SignUp"
          method="POST"
          className="flex flex-col gap-6 mt-10 justify-center items-center h-[250px] absolute bottom-[17rem]"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        >
          <input
          name="Name"
            className="bg-[#1c1d1e] w-[30rem] h-[3rem] font-light text-sm pl-5"
            value="default value"
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder="NAME"
            type="text"
            {...register("Name")}
          />
          <input
          name="Email"
            className="bg-[#1c1d1e] w-[30rem] h-[3rem] font-light text-sm pl-5"
            value="default value"
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder="EMAIL"
            type="text"
            {...register("Email")}
          />
          <input
          name="Password"
            className="bg-[#1c1d1e] w-[30rem] h-[3rem] font-light text-sm pl-5"
            value="default value"
            autoComplete="off"
            placeholder="PASSWORD"
            type={type}
            {...register("Password")}
          />
          <button
            className="absolute right-[20px] bottom-[69px] "
            onClick={togglePassword}
          >
            <img
              className="invert w-[1.5rem]"
              ref={passwordIcon}
              src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/528962/eye.svg"
              alt="img not foud"
            />
          </button>
          <button
            className="text-sm font-semibold border-2 w-28 h-8 rounded-[5px]"
            type="submit"
          >
            <NavLink to="/">SUBMIT</NavLink>
          </button>
        </form>

this is my server code
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const localStrategy = require("passport-local");
const expressSession = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const User = require("./user");
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 3000;
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// app.use(express.json)
app.use(cors());

app.use(
  expressSession({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: "this is secret",
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/SignUp");
});

app.post("/SignUp", async function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body)

  const user = new User({
    name: req.body.Name,
    email: req.body.Email,
  });

  User.register(user, req.body.Password).then(() => {
    passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/");
    });
  });
  console.log(user);
});


Tried to ask chatgpt but it didn't help me. I am new to this, like currently i am in a learning phase. Stuck in this since 3-4 days.

Have you checked that from the front-end (ReactJS), you are sending the request body correctly to the back-end? If yes, can you share with us what is the sent request body in the question? You can check it from the Browser DevTools (F12), network tab and the request based on the URL. Thanks.

I would guess that you are sending a form instead of a json

@YongShun thanks for your reply, actually the "SUBMIT" was creating the problem, i removed the navlink tag and now its working fine. The data is now getting stored in the database but i encountered another error "POST localhost:3000/SignUp 400 (Bad Request)" and also it is not redirecting me to "localhost:3001" after the signup completion.

Bad request is a client-side error, which means that you are not sending the correct value to your back-end, probably like an incorrect data type, back-end unable to read the received request correctly etc.

@YongShun it's showing that there is an error in the onSubmit function. Can you please rectify it if possible
